# Error while running, works fine on the build

Tags: java, runtimeexception

First, this is for a school class.
This is my program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exitearly1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your name: ");
        String name = kbinput.next();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < name.length()) {
            count++;
            int res = name.charAt(count);
            if ((res == 'a') || (res == 'A'))
                continue;
            System.out.println(name.charAt(count));
        }
        System.out.println("Name with no A's");
    }
}
```

It prints what I am inputting (Andrea) without A's like it is suppose to, but after doing so instead of printing out that last line it gives me this in the output:

```
n
d
r
e
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at Exitearly1.main(Exitearly1.java:13)
```

I tried many different ways to fix it with nothing changing it, I am coming here because I asked my teacher how to fix it, and she only told me what was wrong with it which I already knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating from position *1* to position *name.length()*, so you're going out of range (since stringvar.charAt(stringvar.length()) always results in an out of range exception.

Orel's solution will probably end in an infinite loop. You should do something like this:

```
while (count < name.length())
{       
    int res = name.charAt(count);
    if (( res !='a')&&(res !='A')) {
      System.out.println(name.charAt(count));
    }
    count++;
}
```

Please note that your code never shows the first position of the String, independently of it being an 'A' or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

While others pointed out your mistake (you increased counter before you used it to read character at position described by it) I would suggest to use enhanced for loop (it can iterate over arrays, or instances of classes which implements `Iterable` interface ), something like

```
for (char ch : name.toCharArray()){
    if ((ch == 'a') || (ch  == 'A'))
        continue;
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```